# How do I access/create topics on firebase pubsub emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-cli

I've added/setup the firebase pubsub emulator that is running on my localhost on port 8085. Up till this point I had need to use the pubsub in Googel cloud, where I would use their console to create topics and could also review messages published to those topics.

Now that it's running locally, there doesn't seem to be a UI to manage topics/messages and I can't seem to find documentation that explains how to create a topic on the local pubsub, how to review existing topics and how to review messages?

In addition, if I am writing a cloud function that references the pubsub library, will it automatically use my local emulator version if it's running or do I need to specify the host/port in my node.js function someplace? Any examples of this out there?

I believe their is an http API I Can use to create topics,but again, I can't find any documentation on this or find references to see what topics exist and what messages have been sent to the topics.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect your app to the local emulator you must set some environment variables like explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#prototype_interactively)

About the UI of the emulator you can access it on http://localhost:4000 like this [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#prototype_interactively) mentions, although I am not sure if there are management tools to manage topics or messages in there.

Comment: FYI, what I found out , at least for firebase emulator, is that if it's running locally, the code will automatically use the emulator versus cloud version. Also, there was no need for me to create the topics ahead of time....I could publish to a topic and the onpublish event would just "work" and pick up messages locally. So, all is good!

Comment: Any way to use the prod pubsub while using the emulator? I want to get the prod messages in dev emulator env